# How to create div inside another div using prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

my goal is to create div inside another one, but I need to use prototypes for that. To be honest I'm new to programming. I know those objects should have something in common with inheritance, but I couldn't find anything that resolve my problem.

There is a code in HTML

```
<input type="button" value="div" onclick='ND.createDiv()'>
<input type="button" value="divInside" onclick="NDI.insideCreateDiv()">

<div id='main'></div>
```

And there is JavaScript code

```
function Div(text, type){
    this.text = text;
    this.type = type;
}

Div.prototype.createDiv = function(){
    this.type = document.createElement('div');
    this.type.innerHTML = this.text;
    main.appendChild(this.type);
}

Div.prototype.insideCreateDiv = function(){
    let parent = this.type;
    const child = document.createElement('div');
    child.innerHTML = this.text;
    parent.appendChild(child);
}

const ND = new Div('helloDIV', 'div');
const NDI = new Div('helloInsideDIV', 'div');
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: "but I need to use prototypes for that" what does it mean? Why do you use "this"? Is it a class?

Comment: Did somebody tell you, you have to use prototypes for an exercise? It's pretty unusual to do something so trivial in this manner. Furthermore, how are you planning to connect the two entities (parent and child div)?

Comment: I'm using 'this' because that was the first idea I had in mind, I'm not sure how to explain this better, but I will try: I need to create prototype path which leads to creating a DOM object with text inside. Afterwards I need those objects to create another object inside of them everytime the button will be clicked. This is one of the weirdest exercises I have seen, and yes I have been told to do this that way

Comment: @willn0rd Can you be a bit more specific about the functionality you're looking for? Will you just have these 2 buttons? The first button adding a div with the text `helloDIV` and the second button adding a div inside the first div with the text `helloInsideDIV`? What is supposed to happen if you press the second button before the first? What happens if you press the second button multiple times?

Comment: I will have 8 (2x div, 2x paragraph, 2x span, 2x h5) buttons in total, rest of the buttons will be responsible for the same thing as div buttons. First button create let's call it a bucket div, then second button create div's inside the previous one as many times as button will be clicked. Nothing should happend if you click second before first.

Comment: You could make the parent div an optional 3rd constructor parameter, for example. Or let `createDiv()` have an optional `parent` parameter, in which case you can remove `insideCreateDiv`. It is easiest to use the return value of createElement() as the parent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to use prototypes.

A simple way of doing this is by adding any extra information/configuration to the button themselves and read their values on the click listeners

```js
var parent = document.querySelector("#main");

document.querySelectorAll("[data-bucket]").forEach(function(button) {
  var type = button.getAttribute("data-bucket");
  var bucket;

  button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (bucket) return;
    bucket = document.createElement(type);
    if (button.hasAttribute("data-text")) bucket.appendChild(new Text(button.getAttribute("data-text")));
    parent.appendChild(bucket);
  });

  var childButton = document.querySelector("[data-child='" + type + "']");
  if (!childButton) return;

  childButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!bucket) return;
    var child = document.createElement(type);
    if (childButton.hasAttribute("data-text")) child.appendChild(new Text(childButton.getAttribute("data-text")));
    bucket.appendChild(child);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="div" data-bucket="div" data-text="helloDIV" />
<input type="button" value="divInside" data-child="div" data-text="helloInsideDIV" />
<input type="button" value="p" data-bucket="p" data-text="helloP" />
<input type="button" value="pInside" data-child="p" data-text="helloInsideP" />

<div id='main'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I want to apologize for bad explenation. After some time i figured out what exactly I have to do, if someone is interested I will leave a code:

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');

let layer1 = null;
let layer2 = null;
let layer3 = null;
let layer4 = null;

class Bucket{
    constructor(name, text){
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
    }

    Layer1(){
        layer1 = document.createElement(this.name);
        layer1.innerHTML = this.text;
        main.appendChild(layer1)
    }

    Layer2(){
        layer2 = document.createElement(this.name);
        layer2.innerHTML = this.text;
        layer1.appendChild(layer2);
    }

    Layer3(){
        layer3 = document.createElement(this.name);
        layer3.innerHTML = this.text;
        layer2.appendChild(layer3);
    }

    Layer4(){
        layer4 = document.createElement(this.name);
        layer4.innerHTML = this.text;
        layer3.appendChild(layer4);
    }
}


const L1_D = new Bucket('div', 'div');
const L1_P  = new Bucket('p', 'paragraph');
const L1_S  = new Bucket('span', 'span');
const L1_H  = new Bucket('h5', 'h5');

const L2_D = Object.create(L1_D);
const L2_P = Object.create(L1_P);
const L2_S = Object.create(L1_S);
const L2_H = Object.create(L1_H);

const L3_D = Object.create(L2_D);
const L3_P = Object.create(L2_D);
const L3_S = Object.create(L2_D);
const L3_H = Object.create(L2_D);

const L4_D = Object.create(L3_D);
const L4_P = Object.create(L3_D);
const L4_S = Object.create(L3_D);
const L4_H = Object.create(L3_D);
```

```html
<input type='button' value='1 Layer' onclick='L1_D.Layer1(); this.onclick=null;'>
    <input type='button' value='2 Layer' onclick='L2_D.Layer2(); this.onclick=null;'>
    <input type='button' value='3 Layer' onclick='L3_D.Layer3(); this.onclick=null;'>
    <input type='button' value='4 Layer' onclick='L4_D.Layer4(); this.onclick=null;'>
    
    <input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">

    <div id='main'></div>
```